# Why is the closed gain loop -3dB from the open loop gain rather than some other value?

Tags: circuit-analysis, control, control-system, feedback

I am reading the book *Op Amps for Everyone* and in the chapter of feedback loop theory, I have this quote (see picture) where it says in reality the closed loop gain is down by 3dB at the point X as shown below.

How does he know it is -3dB and not some other value that is proportional to the gain B?

[image]

[image]

page number 85, link to the book:[Op Amps for Everyone](http://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf)

Comment: The -3dB point is **by definition** the point at which we read the frequency (x-axis) to determine the bandwidth. It is the same as with a simple RC filter, a 1 kHz lowpass filter has an attenuation of -3 dB at 1 kHz. If your simple RC filter attenuates -1 dB at 1 kHz then it's not a 1 kHz filter! So the author doesn't somehow "know" it should be -3 dB, instead it is a **standard way to define the bandwidth**.

Comment: so he refers directly to cut off frequency. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The text says it's a single pole amplifier circuit and that always means that at the cut-off frequency, due to the transfer function gain equation, the output signal is down to exactly half the power of the input signal. Half the power in decibels is \$10\log_{10}(0.5) =\$ -3.0103 dB.

That's what single pole filters do at their cut-off frequency.

Comment: The order of the LPF is irrelevant to the defined amplitude response BW at -3dB !!  Not because it is a single pole !! kinda misleading.

Comment: I'm just describing a single pole filter. If I said that all boys have two biological parents would I be wrong? Of course, the bigger picture is that everyone has two parents.

Comment: so could someone infer a 2nd order filter is -6dB ? yes if they cascaded two same 1st order , no the BW is defined by -3dB and thus BW will be reduced. See the ambiguity it might cause?  But you might be a test tube baby (lol)

Comment: My sister is [Louise Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louise_Brown)... Well actually she's called Louise and our shared surname begins Br.... so that's near enough for me.

Comment: Really good music on your site

Comment: You old rocker you.

Comment: @Andyaka. Sorry to ask you again but I have to, to clarify it once more. I do understand that the single pole filter has -3dB at their cutoff frequency. My confusion comes from that 20*log(A) is the gain at open loop and also has cut off frequency 97dB if I suppose 20*log(A) =100dB at DC. then in closed loop the gain 20*log(Vout/Vin) would be different and if I suppose that it is 14dB at DC, so the the gain at cut off frequency (point X) would be 14dB-3dB=11dB in closed loop gain.

Comment: so 20log(Vout/Vin)=20log(A)-20log(1+AB)
14dB=100dB-86dB which means 20log(1+AB)=86dB. this confuses me because each closed loop gain value has its own cut off frequency of DCgain-3dB or I am wrong?

Comment: The closed loop gain will be 3 dB lower but at a much higher frequency. If I’ve not been clear, leave another message and I’ll try again tomorrow @Yaakov

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you. okay I agree that the closed loop gain will be 3db lower but lower to DC gain of the closed loop gain and not the open loop gain? Right?

Comment: @Yaakov it will be 3 dB lower than the closed loop DC gain.

Answer (score 4):

ALL filters regardless of type, shape or order are defined by the half-power points in the passband or -3.01 dB or 0.707 V.  This is simply the amplitude response ***by definition defined by half-power.***

But,  there are many other complex filters that have more important specs like linear-phase or group-delay flatness to -6 or -12 dB or PB ripple in dB using higher Q offset f for steep skirts or band stop BW and attenuation.  For Chebychev Filters the skirts are steeper by staggering higher Q filters and the **equal ripple** filter is defined by **the BW limited by the ripple in the band and where it exceeds this dB ripple** at the edge, which is more important than the half-power point. (ty LVW)

This is why no other value is used for ***basic passband amplitude response.***

Comment: Just for the sake of exactness: All Chebyshev and Cauer (elliptical) responses have a path band which is defined by the ripple within this band (and NOT by half-power points).

Comment: Yes but the ripple BW is separate from the amplitude response BW, so these are defined by both parameters

Comment: I don`t think that - for Chebyshev and Cauer responses - we have two different pass band definitions at the same time. Look at the pole parameter tables in relevant books and/or study the filter design programs - all use the ripple properties for defining the passband. And this makes much sense!! Mote than that, in some cases, for the Bessel response the passband edge is defined in the time domain (group delay flatness).

Comment: Again multiple specs for complex filters. I design Bessel for the range in dB like -6dB or -12dB and Cheb by dB and Linear phase to 2ndary BW and deg. then  Raised Cosine to Q but Amplitude response remains the same fo= -3dB where BPF have 2 such points. When Cheb ripple becomes 0dB it is a Butterworth

Comment: I must admit that I have problems to regard your comment as an answer to my comment. Therefore, one single clear and simple question: Do you agree that there is a common understanding (which is reflected in all the available filter tables) that the passband edge of a Chebysheff lowpass of any order is defined by the (last occurence of the) allowed passband ripple? For example: 0.1, 0.5 or 1 dB?

Comment: Excerpt from "Acrive Network Design with Signal Filtering Applications" (Claude S. Lindquist): "The cutoff frequency corresponds to the point where the gain is reduced by the amount of ripple (rather than 3 dB for the Butterworth filter)." End of quote.

Comment: TY LvW that makes sense as the Ripple is more critical than the -3dB point